# How to refactor this foreach map loop for react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

Considering this code how would you revise it with a array map?

````
    ActivityHistory(form) {
        let activities = form.activities
        let result = [];
        activities(function(activity) {
            result.push($(
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' +
                        Laravel.ActionPlanActivity.ACTIVITY_TYPES[activity.type].title +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="text-center">' +
                        (activity.done_at ? moment(activity.done_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY') : "") +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="text-center">' +
                        activity.status +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>'
            ));
        });
        return result;
    }
    ```




I have tried to do it like this?
````

```
ActivityHistory(form) {
    let result = [];
    result = form.activities.map(activity =>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {Laravel.ActionPlanActivity.ACTIVITY_TYPES[activity.type].title}
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                {(activity.done_at ? moment(activity.done_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY') : "")}
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                {activity.status}
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
    return result;
}
```

```
Which returns this error...

> v2.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at e.value (v2.js:32)
    at e.value (v2.js:32)
    at t.value (v2.js:53)
    at p._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (react-dom.min.js:11)
    at p._renderValidatedComponent (react-dom.min.js:11)
    at performInitialMount (react-dom.min.js:11)
    at p.mountComponent (react-dom.min.js:11)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.min.js:12)
    at mountChildren (react-dom.min.js:12)
    at m._createInitialChildren (react-dom.min.js:11)

[![Activities Array... console.log][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU2bl.png
```

Comment: which part are you having trouble with? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It's also a little hard to tell from your code what `activities` the function does

Comment: All it does is loop through an array of items and get create a table row...

Comment: Just use `.map`, and change the string concatenation to be JSX. Which part specifically are you having issues with?